# I want to modualrise code using javascript

Tags: javascript, modularity

I have one file in which there is lot of code in one function. Say that function name is MessageHandler and in that function there is lot of if else condition and code to be executed after condition is true. The problem is i want to modularised that code using javascript so that it would be maintainable and also it would be easy to find bugs. May be creating different files for every logic.What is the best approach

Part of the Code:

```
if (userMessage == "/start" && event.channel == "ibc") {
        quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction.english;
        quickReplies.msgid = "afterIntro";
        quickReplies.options = metaData.language.english;

        context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(quickReplies));//First introduction message is sent in english language.

    }

        else if (userMessage == "hi" || userMessage == "hello" || userMessage == "help" || userMessage == "hii" || userMessage == "hey" || userMessage == "wassup") {
        // add filipino and gujarati condition....
        if (context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang == "hindi") {
            quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction.hindi;
            quickReplies.options = metaData.language.hindi;
        } 

    else if(context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang=="gujarati"){

                quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction.gujarati;
            quickReplies.options = metaData.language.gujarati
        }
            else if(context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang=="filipino"){

                quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction.filipino;
            quickReplies.options = metaData.language.filipino;
        }


        else {
            quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction.english;
            quickReplies.options = metaData.language.english;
        }
        quickReplies.msgid = "afterIntro";

        context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(quickReplies));


    } else if (event.messageobj.refmsgid == "afterIntro" || (userMessage.indexOf("change category") > -1) || (userMessage.indexOf("श्रेणी बदलें") > -1) ||(userMessage.indexOf("કેટેગરી બદ") > -1) ||(userMessage.indexOf("baguhin ang kategorya") > -1)) {
        if (userMessage == "अंग्रेजी" || userMessage == "english" || userMessage == "ઇંગલિશ" ||userMessage=="ingles")
        {
            context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang = "english";
            context.console.log("Enter into english section");
            // context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '1';
            userMessage = "english";
        } else if (userMessage == "हिंदी" || userMessage == "hindi" || userMessage == "હિન્દી") 
        {
            context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang = "hindi";
            // context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '1';
            userMessage = "hindi";
        } else if (userMessage == "गुजराती" || userMessage == "gujarati" || userMessage == "ગુજરાતી"){
            context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang = "gujarati";
            // context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '1'ફિલિપિનો"
            userMessage = "gujarati";
        } else if (userMessage == "filipino" || userMessage == "फिलिपिनो" || userMessage == "ફિલિપિનો") {
            context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang = "filipino";
            // context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '1'ફિલિપિનો"

            userMessage = "filipino";
        } else {
            userMessage = context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang
            // context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '1';
        }
        var languageArray = metaData.language.english;
        for (var i = 0; i < languageArray.length; i++) {
            if (userMessage == metaData.language.english[i]) {
                console.log("language"+metaData.language.english[i]);
                quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introMessage[metaData.language.english[i].toString()];
                quickReplies.msgid = "afterLanguage";
                quickReplies.options = metaData[metaData.language.english[i].toString()];
                context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(quickReplies));///Intro message and categories to choose from.
            }
        }
    } else if (userMessage == 'change language' || (userMessage.indexOf('hindi') > -1) || (userMessage.indexOf('english') > -1) || (userMessage.indexOf('gujarati') > -1)|| (userMessage.indexOf('filipino') > -1)) {
        var currentLanguage = context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang;
        quickReplies.content.text = metaData.introduction[currentLanguage + 'language'];
        quickReplies.options = metaData.language[currentLanguage];
        quickReplies.msgid = "afterIntro";
        context.console.log("currentLanguage=======" + currentLanguage);
        context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(quickReplies));////give option to change the language in preferred language with prefereed messsage describing what to do.
    } else if (userMessage == 'powered by gupshup') {
        context.sendResponse("This chatbot is powered by gupshup.io- world's leading filipinoform." +
            " Join the bot bandwagon along with- VentureBeat, Infosys, Sage, ICICI etc. " +
            "to build captivating and powerful experiences for your users.");
    } else if (event.messageobj.refmsgid == "afterLanguage")
    // }else if(context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag == '1')
    {
        context.simpledb.roomleveldata.optinFlag = '0';
        var quoteType;
        var items = [];
        var currentLanguage = context.simpledb.roomleveldata.preferredLang;
        for (var i = 0; i < metaData[currentLanguage].length; i++) //["Motivational", "Love", "Life", "Funny", "Positive"]
        {
            quoteType = metaData[currentLanguage][i].toLowerCase().toString(); //["Motivational", "Love", "Life", "Funny", "Positive"]
            context.console.log(userMessage + "--------quoteType----" + quoteType);
            if (userMessage == quoteType) {
                context.console.log("Cureeeeentttt quote typeeeee"+userMessage);
                catalogue.msgid = quoteType;
                // if(currentLanguage == "filipino")
                // {
                //  quoteType = metaData['english'][i+1].toLowerCase().toString(); //
                // }else
                // {
                    quoteType = metaData['english'][i].toLowerCase().toString(); // 
                // }

                    quoteType=quoteType.replace(/ /g,"_");
                    context.console.log("QQQQQQQQQQQQUOTEEEEEEE"+quoteType);
                var imageURL = context.simpledb.botleveldata[quoteType + 'JSONObj'];
                context.console.log("imageURL--------" + imageURL);
                if(JSON.stringify(imageURL).indexOf(currentLanguage)>-1)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < imageURL.length; j++) // {["ImageURL:'',Language:''"]}
                    {
                        context.console.log(imageURL[j]['Language'].toString() + "---------currentLanguage" + currentLanguage);
                            if (imageURL[j]['Language'].toString() == currentLanguage) {
                                context.console.log("imageURL[j]['Language'].toString()==============" + imageURL[j]['Language'].toString())
                                if (j % 9 == 0 && j != 0) {
                                    items.push({
                                        "title": "For More Quotes",
                                        "imgurl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gs-bot-images/Quote-Mister/search.jpg",
                                        "options": [{
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "title": "Keep Looking"
                                        }]
                                    });
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                    items.push({
                                        "title": metaData.carousal[currentLanguage + "_title"],
                                        "imgurl": imageURL[j]['Image URL'].toString(),
                                        "options": [{
                                            "type": "url",
                                            "title": "Preview",
                                            "url": imageURL[j]['Image URL'].toString()
                                        }, {
                                            "type": "url",
                                            "title": metaData.carousal[currentLanguage + '_button_text'][0],
                                            "url": "https://www.gupshup.io/developer/bot/devNewImageQuotes/share?text=" + imageURL[j]['Image URL'].toString(),
                                            "webview_height_ratio": "compact"
                                        }, {
                                            "type": "url",
                                            "title": metaData.carousal[currentLanguage + '_button_text'][1],
                                            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + imageURL[j]['Image URL'].toString(),
                                            "webview_height_ratio": "compact"
                                        }]
                                    });
                                    context.simpledb.roomleveldata['index'] = j;
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Look into ES6 modules: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/ and webpack: https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: No, don't think about many files for now. Just write many small functions at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [patterns](http://tcorral.github.io/Design-Patterns-in-Javascript/) like a module.
Do your code more legible, like a history, put each piece of code in one function and keep these functions in files where make sense be there, and when you need help calling as follow:

```js
doActionOne()
doOtherAction(params)
isValidAction() // use is to validate true/false
```

Here has a famous [Design Pattern Book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).
:)

Comment: thanks, I know that we can use module pattern in this case.But should i create function or file for each if/else condition??

Comment: First of all, thinking in your example, I would put validate message file, and I'd create a function to validate thinks like userMessage and event true/false and after, make it userMessage validate receive ...params, so can use some function array or includes. Do functions to clean your code, after that, in the future, you will refactor better, just to not wast time.

Comment: Ok..But i have different response for different message how i could make it more generic function to all sorts input and send reply according to that??

Comment: Ok, so I think you need to turn your answers in Factory functions, where your return is different for each parameter. [link](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e)